# How to print text files using CUPS configurably

Tags: text-formatting, printing, cups

When I try to print a text file using CUPS, it comes out with a very small font and negligible margins:

```
head -n 450 /usr/share/dict/words | tr '\n' " " > t
/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf 1 1 1 1 1 t > t.pdf
```

[image: text with no margins]

How can I configure the font and the margins that are used for printing text files? Is there a system configuration file, or some bit of command-line magic that I can execute, to do this? For example, I may want a size 12 font, and 1 inch margins all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on `texttopdf` filter is sparse and information sometimes has to be deduced, but for example, from the usage output itself when you invoke `texttopdf` without any arguments,

```
Usage: texttopdf job-id user title copies options [file]
```

and some resources like [cups-filters Github page](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters) and [Debian wiki on texttopdf filter](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTextToPdfFilter) one can guess that `texttopdf` accepts the same arguments as lp(1)/lpr(1)'s `-o` switch, with the added restriction that all options need to be gathered into a single argument by quoting. [lp-cups(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lp-cups) lists all of the accepted options in CUPS. Some of the more interesting options, for example, are:

- `landscape`, which sets the output to landscape mode
- `cpi=<value>`, which sets the number of characters per inch (default is 10 according to [lp-cups(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lp-cups))
- `lpi=<value>`, which sets the number of lines per inch (default is 6 according to [lp-cups(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lp-cups))

The exact values for `lpi=` and `cpi=` which suit your needs would have to be calculated from the paper size and font glyph sizes, and perhaps it is easier to discover them by trial and error.

The `texttopdf` also functions as any Unix command with regards to stdin/stdout, so there is no need for intermediate files.

For example, you could use:

```
head -n 450 /usr/share/dict/words | tr '\n' ' ' | \
    /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf 1 1 1 1 'cpi=15 lpi=8 landscape' \
    > words.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason those `lp` options are not documented in my distribution's version of `lp(1)`. I see I can also specify margins with e.g. `page-bottom=36 page-top=36 page-left=72 page-right=72`. It would be nice to be able to specify font and font size, as by passing the wrong values to `cpi` and `lpi` it is possible to get strange aspect ratios.

Comment: @Metamorphic Yes, as stated the exact values to set cpi/lpi to in order to preserve glyph proportions depend on both paper and glyph metrics within the font. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to specify the size of letters by giving point size.